# Codenameone : How to create a circular badge with CSS?

Tags: css, codenameone

So I was trying to create a circular badge using CSS in codenameone but so far I have been unlucky or my approach was wrong.

I wanted to create a price badge with circular green background like this :

[image]

I am using this CSS style :

```
MenuCardPrice{
        color: white;
        font-size: 8pt;
        background: #338833;
        border-radius: 50px;
        height : 100px;
        width :100px;
}
```

But I get a badge like this :

[image]

I tried changing the height  and width of the style and tried being `border-radius: 50%` as well but that does not make much difference.

On top of that if I try to increase the radius of it the size of the container/Label increases rather than increasing the curve like this : 
[image]

What is the correct way to create a circular badge in Codenameone using CSS?

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing:border-box`? It seems likely that your element is not *actually* square.

Comment: No I am not using anything special I have exact style as I have mentioned on the question.

Comment: Then demonstrate the problem. My guess is that you have additional padding in there somewhere.

Comment: It's not pure CSS and there is no padding, Its a CSS port of Codenameone it is missing some native CSS implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the CSS section of the developer guide here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html

```css
RoundBorderFilled {
    background: cn1-round-border;
    color: white;
    font-size: 8mm;
    background: #338833;
    text-align:center;
    padding:3mm;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you Shai. Will look into this docs in details